# How could I disable the submit button before all fields are valid

Tags: angularjs

Currently, I know how to set validation for each field.

But I have no idea how could I disable the submit button before all fields are valid.

And enable the submit button once all fields are valid.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <span ng-messages="form.name.$error" class="alert">
        <span ng-message="required">{{I18n.t("required_field_could_not_be_empty")}}</span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="payment_contact.name" required="required" name="name">
</div>

....

   <label>Email</label>
    <span ng-class="{'alert':form.email_booking.$error.email}" ng-show="form.email_booking.$error.email" >
    {{I18n.t("invalid_format")}}
    </span>
    <input type="email" id="email_booking" name="email_booking" class="form-control" ng-model="payment_contact.email">
</div>                            

<a ng-click="place_order()" class="btn_1 green medium">Book now</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the `ng-submit` directive

This will only allow you to submit if the form is valid.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit

Answer (score 1):

Since your form already has a name (form) simply add `ng-disabled="form.$invalid"` to your button (link?).